SWR shows data undefined at first render
I am trying to get used to Next.js' version. Before I was using getServerSideProps and sending the data to client side so I was getting the data at first render without seeing undefined. I didn't understand how to achieve the same thing in the latest version (next.js 14).
Here is my code:
Home page:
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import ListTasks from "@/components/ListTasks/ListTasks";
import Modal from "@/components/Modal/Modal";
import useGetData from "@/hooks/useGetData";

export default function Home() {
  const [modalProps, setModalProps] = useState({
    isOpen: false,
    type: "",
  });
  const data = useGetData();
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-500 w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
      {modalProps.isOpen && (
        <Modal modalProps={modalProps} setModalProps={setModalProps} />
      )}
      <div className="bg-gray-400 w-1/3 h-3/4 rounded">
        <p className="text-white text-center text-2xl font-bold">To-do App</p>
        <div className="w-10 h-10 bg-black rounded flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer">
          <p
            className="text-white text-6xl pb-2"
            onClick={() =>
              setModalProps({ ...modalProps, isOpen: true, type: "post" })
            }
          >
            +
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-red-300 indent-5 rounded m-3 py-1">
          <ListTasks modalProps={modalProps} setModalProps={setModalProps} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

useGetData hook:
import useSWR from "swr";

export default function useGetData() {
  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR("/api/get", fetcher);

  return data;
}

What can I do to get the data at first render without seeing undefined?

import useSWR from "swr";

export default function useGetData() {
  const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then((res) => res.json());
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR("/api/get", fetcher);

  return { data, error, isLoading, isError }
}

In the main page
const { data, error, isLoading ,isError } = useGetData();

if (isLoading){
   return <div>Loading......</div>;
}

if (isError){
   return <div>Error occured......</div>;
}

 return (
    <div className="bg-slate-500 w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
      {modalProps.isOpen && (
        <Modal modalProps={modalProps} setModalProps={setModalProps} />
      )}
      <div className="bg-gray-400 w-1/3 h-3/4 rounded">
        <p className="text-white text-center text-2xl font-bold">To-do App</p>
        <div className="w-10 h-10 bg-black rounded flex justify-center items-center cursor-pointer">
          <p
            className="text-white text-6xl pb-2"
            onClick={() =>
              setModalProps({ ...modalProps, isOpen: true, type: "post" })
            }
          >
            +
          </p>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-red-300 indent-5 rounded m-3 py-1">
          <ListTasks modalProps={modalProps} setModalProps={setModalProps} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );



I know this, but it is not my desired intention. As I mentioned: When I was using Next.js < 13, I was using getServerSideProps and sending the data to client side from getServerSideProps. So I wasn't seeing 'undefined' nor needed 'Loading' message. I want to learn the same approach in the latest version so that I am not going to need Loading message.

https://swr.vercel.app/docs/getting-started this doc also metions the loading state of SWR

Yes I am aware of this, as well. But it just doesn't make sense that they removed such a feature so I think, there needs to be a way. Thanks for taking time.


Before I was using getServerSideProps and sending the data to client
side so I was getting the data at first render without seeing
undefined

When you navigate to a page that uses getServerSideProps, Next.js runs this function during the server-side rendering (SSR) process. The data fetched in getServerSideProps is then passed as props to your React component, allowing you to have access to it on the first render without the initial state being undefined. This eliminates the need to handle loading states for data fetching on the initial page load, as the page is served with all the necessary data already in place.
swr is reach hook library, hook library can be run only client side.  when you do client side data fetching, fetching starts only after the JavaScript has loaded and the React component has mounted. This means the initial render of the component doesn't have the fetched data. Because fetching data from the client side is asynchronous, the component renders initially without the data, necessitating handling of loading states. During the initial fetch, SWR transitions to a loading state. While in the loading state, you typically display a loading spinner. Once the data fetching is complete, SWR transitions from the loading state to the data state. The component re-renders with the fetched data, allowing you to display the actual content to the user.

So at the end, I achieved my desired intention. Here is an explanation of what I did:
Firstly, I was using "use client" on Home page. I removed it and turned the page into a server component. I had "use client" on Home page because I was using useState. So I decided to create a context for that state as I was using it in multiple components.
Then I created one more component - ListTasksClient - . I did this because I used ListTasks component as a server component and fetched the data there by using Fetch API and send the data as prop to ListTasksClient. So the data was ready in initial render.
Bonus:
One thing I realized - I may be wrong - , I couldn't fetch the data from api folder when I was using server component. So because of this reason I created a helper function and used it on both api folder and server component to get the tasks.
Hope this can be helpful.
